# Helios Annoyance: Internal error occurred during: "Cache refresh" - NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception, internal, eclipse-3.6, helios

I am not sure what started this problem.  I submitted it as a bug to Eclipse but they closed it, stating it is a JBoss extension problem.  However, this problem doesn't occur in my other workspace (both utilize the JBoss tools).

It occurs every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new type.  It only reports the "Cache Refresh" error. Then when I type in a search string and hit OK, it pops up both the "Cache Refresh" error and a "Items filtering" error.  Both of these report NPEs.

I inspected the logs but don't see anything jboss-specific in the stacks.

**Cache refresh:**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2011-04-19 11:55:05.983
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Cache refresh".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.classpath.core.ejb3.EJB3ClasspathContainer.getClasspathEntries(EJB3ClasspathContainer.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2656)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2788)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1920)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaWorkspaceScope.enclosingProjectsAndJars(JavaWorkspaceScope.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.IndexSelector.initializeIndexLocations(IndexSelector.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.IndexSelector.getIndexLocations(IndexSelector.java:276)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.selectIndexes(JavaSearchParticipant.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.getIndexes(PatternSearchJob.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.ensureReadyToRun(PatternSearchJob.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.performConcurrentJob(JobManager.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(BasicSearchEngine.java:1135)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(SearchEngine.java:744)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog$ConsistencyRunnable.refreshSearchIndices(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog$ConsistencyRunnable.run(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:637)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.reloadCache(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:680)
        at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredItemsSelectionDialog$RefreshCacheJob.run(FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java:1508)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

**Items Filtering:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.classpath.core.ejb3.EJB3ClasspathContainer.getClasspathEntries(EJB3ClasspathContainer.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2656)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2788)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1920)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaWorkspaceScope.enclosingProjectsAndJars(JavaWorkspaceScope.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.IndexSelector.initializeIndexLocations(IndexSelector.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.IndexSelector.getIndexLocations(IndexSelector.java:276)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.selectIndexes(JavaSearchParticipant.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.getIndexes(PatternSearchJob.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.ensureReadyToRun(PatternSearchJob.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.performConcurrentJob(JobManager.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(BasicSearchEngine.java:1135)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(SearchEngine.java:846)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.dialogs.FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.fillContentProvider(FilteredTypesSelectionDialog.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredItemsSelectionDialog$FilterJob.filterContent(FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java:2188)
        at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredItemsSelectionDialog$FilterJob.internalRun(FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java:2130)
        at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredItemsSelectionDialog$FilterJob.doRun(FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java:2102)
        at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredItemsSelectionDialog$FilterJob.run(FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java:2089)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reinstall Helios (SR2) to make these errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem and did the same thing. to avoid some memory problems with eclipse you can increase the memory use in the eclipse.ini file located in the installation folder, but don't over do it, it depends on your machines ram.