# An internal error occurred during: "Win32 refresh daemon"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I'm facing the following error with Eclipse Juno:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.refresh.win32.Win32Monitor$FileHandle.handleNotification(Win32Monitor.java:94)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.refresh.win32.Win32Monitor.waitForNotification(Win32Monitor.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.refresh.win32.Win32Monitor.run(Win32Monitor.java:501)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Apparently is related with [Internal error occurred during: “Cache refresh”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719252/helios-annoyance-internal-error-occurred-during-cache-refresh-nullpointere).
Are there any thing that may solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete and reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the Eclipse with -clean argument solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the error persists, uncheck the checkbox under Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or polling.

Eclipse automatically refreshes the workspace, if some other tool modifies the underlying file system outside Eclipse. Your error happened in the background job doing that work.

Of course you may have to refresh the workspace manually with that option disabled.